# Android Studio Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver... Directory Doesnt Exist?

Tags: android

I am new to android studio and I have been trying to figure out how to install this driver. Also I am just following youtube guides, do I need to use AVD or just a nice thing. I am making really simple app. Already have layout just want to add some code behind the buttons that I already wrote out in eclipse. I am getting this message `Unable to run Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installer: Cannot start process, the working directory 'C:\Users\Drew\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver' does not exist`

EDIT (SOLVED): https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/10/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for.html

Comment: Instead of editing your question and answering there: consider to write a self answer, and accept that.